# How do I set a default language (input source) for an application?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, keyboard-layout, osx-mountain-lion, input-languages

*Has Apple completely removed the possibility to do this, and to what end?*

The primary input language for my MacBook is Norwegian. What I want is for OSX to open MacVim with the US input language instead of Norwegian.

In other words, I want to be able to set a default input language (input source) to an application. I want OSX to **KNOW** which input language to use for MacVim when I launch it, instead of me having to switch it to the input language I want EVERY SINGLE TIME I launch MacVim.

*(From what I have read, this was possible in earlier versions of OSX, then got removed. Why?)*

If this is not possible natively, is there any app which does this? I am getting REALLY desperate.

Best regards,
Krystah

Comment: There's a [similar question at Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28393/auto-change-keyboard-layout-based-on-application-focus), even though it doesn't currently mention anything other than the setting in the input source preferences.

Comment: This only discusses the built-in functionality to change an applications keyboard layout AFTER it has been opened, and this has to be done every single time the program is launched.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround I'm using is to make <kbd>Esc</kbd> always switch back to English within MacVim.  There is a very nice app called [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/), and you can use something like below as its `private.xml` configuration to let MacVim behave in such way.  MacVim might start, or be in a different input source, but you can get it right with a single keystroke, which must be pretty familiar to your fingers already.  Moreover, this is extremely helpful if you're switching back and forth from input mode to/from normal mode in MacVim, entering and editing non-English text.

```
<root>
<item>
    <name>In Vim, Make Escape key also Switch to English IM</name>
    <identifier>private.vim_esc_also_switches_to_english_inputmode</identifier>
    <only>VI</only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::ESCAPE,
    <!---->               KeyCode::ESCAPE,KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTMODE_ENGLISH </autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

See also: [my private.xml in use](https://github.com/netj/dotfiles/blob/ef1991f91a95b52ca84e5730864966546a91a197/Mac/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml#L46).

Answer (score 1):

There should be an option in the settings pane for input where you can select if you want the same global or on application basis.

Edit: It only have "Use same one in all documents" and "Allow a different one for each document"

Not sure that works for applications.

Comment: That only makes OSX remember it until the application closes. The next time I open MacVim I have to set the language again. Again, and again and again. I'm amazed the self-proclaimed "worlds most advanced operating system" requires me to do monkey-work in this manner.