# How to leave only english language in bash shell in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, osx-mountain-lion

I'm using Mac OS X operating system with bash shell and I'm really tired to change keyboard layout every time I switch to shell. Does anyone know how to automatically set english layout after switching to shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to use a different input source for each document (or sometimes window or application) in System Preferences:

[image]

It won't probably be useful in this case though.

You could make pressing F5 focus Terminal and switch to an English input source by using a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <vkopenurldef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_Terminal</name>
    <url>file:///Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app</url>
  </vkopenurldef>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F5, KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_Terminal,
    KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTMODE_ENGLISH</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

I don't know how to change the input source back when focusing another application though.

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

Related questions:

- [How do I set a default language (input source) for an application?](https://superuser.com/questions/459307/how-do-i-set-a-default-language-input-source-for-an-application)
- [Auto change keyboard layout based on application focus](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28393/auto-change-keyboard-layout-based-on-application-focus)
- [Application-specific default keyboard layout in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/157229/application-specific-default-keyboard-layout-in-mac-os-x)